# kivy buildozer ошибка нету apk файла

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, apk, python-3.8

Создаю apk из python3 файла, использую buildozer.
Выдаёт вот такую ошибку:

```
Applying patch: src/patches/SDLActivity.java.patch
Warning: failed to apply patch (exit code 1), assuming it is already applied: src/patches/SDLActivity.java.patch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/buildozer", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('buildozer', 'console_scripts', 'buildozer')()
  File "/home/yelik217890/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/buildozer/scripts/client.py", line 13, in main
    Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/yelik217890/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 1062, in run_command
    self.target.run_commands(args)
  File "/home/yelik217890/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 92, in run_commands
    func(args)
  File "/home/yelik217890/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 104, in cmd_debug
    self.buildozer.build()
  File "/home/yelik217890/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 222, in build
    self.target.build_package()
  File "/home/yelik217890/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 1152, in build_package
    copyfile(join(apk_dir, apk), join(self.buildozer.bin_dir, apk_dest))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 261, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc, open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/yelik217890/checkers/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/checkers/bin/Checkers-0.1-debug.apk'
```

Как исправить? В интернете ищу, ничего не помогает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте удалить kivy и установить следующим образом:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Install Python pip
sudo apt-get install -y curl
sudo apt-get install -y python3-distutils
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
sudo python3 get-pip.py

# Dependencies with SDL2
# Install necessary system packages
sudo apt-get install -y \
python-pip \
build-essential \
git \
python \
python3-dev \
ffmpeg \
libsdl2-dev \
libsdl2-image-dev \
libsdl2-mixer-dev \
libsdl2-ttf-dev \
libportmidi-dev \
libswscale-dev \
libavformat-dev \
libavcodec-dev \
zlib1g-dev

# Dependencies Kivy
sudo pip3 install cython

# Install Kivy
sudo pip3 install kivy

# Dependencies Buildozer
sudo apt install -y \
build-essential \
ccache \
git \
libncurses5:i386 \
libstdc++6:i386 \
libgtk2.0-0:i386 \
libpangox-1.0-0:i386 \
libpangoxft-1.0-0:i386 \
libidn11:i386 \
python2.7 \
python2.7-dev \
openjdk-8-jdk \
unzip \
zlib1g-dev \
zlib1g:i386 \
libltdl-dev \
libffi-dev \
libssl-dev \
autoconf \
autotools-dev
cmake

# Install Buildozer
git clone https://github.com/kivy/buildozer.git
cd buildozer
sudo python3 setup.py install
```